# Debugger skipping a whole if statement

Tags: c, bmp, cs50

```html
/**
 * Copies a BMP piece by piece, just because.
 * All we have to do is change all the red pixels to 


 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./copy infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[1];
    char *outfile = argv[2];

    // open input file 
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 || 
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // determine padding for scanlines
    int padding =  (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            RGBTRIPLE red = {0, 0, 255};
            int same = 0; 
            RGBTRIPLE white = {255, 255, 255};

            if(&red.rgbtRed == &triple.rgbtRed && &red.rgbtGreen != &triple.rgbtRed && &red.rgbtBlue != &triple.rgbtRed)
            {
                same = 1; 
            }

            if(same == 0) //copy the pixel, if the pixel isn't red
            {
                // write RGB triple to outfile
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);    
            }
            if(same == 1)
            {
                fwrite(&white, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }

        }

        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

        // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is more specifically with this one segment of the code:

```js
// temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            RGBTRIPLE red = {0, 0, 255};
            int same = 0; 
            RGBTRIPLE white = {255, 255, 255};

            if(&red.rgbtRed == &triple.rgbtRed && &red.rgbtGreen != &triple.rgbtRed && &red.rgbtBlue != &triple.rgbtRed)
            {
                same = 1; 
            }

            if(same == 0) //copy the pixel, if the pixel isn't red
            {
                // write RGB triple to outfile
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);    
            }
            if(same == 1)
            {
                fwrite(&white, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }
```

I am trying to copy over a bmp file to another file, but get rid of any red and replace it with white (most of this code is not my work, its prewritten code that I am supposed to edit for the assignment), The copy function works, but for some reason detecting red and replacing it with white is not working. Oddly when I use the debugger, it completely skips over this part of the code:

```
 if(&red.rgbtRed == &triple.rgbtRed && &red.rgbtGreen != &triple.rgbtRed && &red.rgbtBlue != &triple.rgbtRed)
        {
            same = 1; 
        }
```

which is where I am detecting if the pixel is red, the debugger acts as if the line doesn't exist.

Comment: `&stuff.other` will return an address, not the actual value. Is that what you want? If I were the compiler, I'd optimize that line away as clearly the expression is always false.

Comment: You're comparing addresses not contents. Get rid of the &.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't compare addresses and you dont need to use the `int same` variable at all.

```
if(red.rgbtRed == triple.rgbtRed && red.rgbtGreen != triple.rgbtRed && red.rgbtBlue != triple.rgbtRed) 
{
    fwrite(&white, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
}
else
{
    fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare addresses, it will always fail. Compare the values, as that results in simple integer comparison

```
if(red.rgbtRed == triple.rgbtRed && red.rgbtGreen != triple.rgbtRed && red.rgbtBlue != triple.rgbtRed) {
    same = 1; 
}
```

Comment: That was it! Still new to addresses and pointers so I don't quite have the hang of it just yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler might detect that this "if" condition is always false, and it optimizes out these lines. Therefore this part of the code is not present in your executable and your debugger does not see it.